# is there a command to make scrapy stop collecting links?

Tags: scrapy

I have a spider currently crawling and I want it to now stop collecting links and just crawl everything it has collected, is there a way to do this? I cannot find anything so far.

Answer (score 2):

scrapy offers different ways to stop the spider (apart from calling `ctrl+c`), that you can find on the [CloseSpider extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider)

You can put that on your `settings.py` file, so something like:

```
CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT = 20 # to stop crawling when reaching 20 seconds
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't want to stop the spider. I want it to finish crawling links it has collected, without collecting more. Is it possible to pause the spider and then tell it to not extract links and then resume it?

Comment: I can't think of anything like that at the moment.